# Is there a way to say for every x values, do this?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Before I start, I am new to Python, so any low-level description would be incredibly helpful!

I have a list of lets say 60 values (representing one hour, from 8:00-9:00) and I want to run average, maximums, minimums, and standard deviation for each set of 15. (I already have the average, max, mins, and STDEV functions). Is there an understandable way to right this that can be easily scaled to 1,000.000+ values?

The way I am currently doing this does not work and is incredibly inefficient, but I have it posted below:

```
def for_15(tank_data):
    for tank in tank_data:
        listfifteen = []
        tank_dict = []
        count = 0
        if count <= 14:
            count = count + 1
            listfifteen.append(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['0-14 Avg'] = avg(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['0-14 Max'] = max(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['0-14 Min'] = min(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['0-14 STDEV'] = stdev(tank_data[tank])
            listfifteen[tank] = tank_dict
            print listfifteen
        elif count <= 29:
            count = count + 1
            listfifteen.append(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['15-29 Avg'] = avg(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['15-29 Max'] = max(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['15-29 Min'] = min(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['15-29 STDEV'] = stdev(tank_data[tank])
            listfifteen[tank] = tank_dict
            print listfifteen
        elif count <= 44:
            count = count + 1
            listfifteen.append(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['30-44 Avg'] = avg(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['30-44 Max'] = max(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['30-44 Min'] = min(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['30-44 STDEV'] = stdev(tank_data[tank])
            listfifteen[tank] = tank_dict
            print listfifteen
        else:
            count = count + 1
            listfifteen.append(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['45-59 Avg'] = avg(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['45-59 Max'] = max(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['45-59 Min'] = min(tank_data[tank])
            tank_dict['45-59 STDEV'] = stdev(tank_data[tank])
            listfifteen[tank] = tank_dict
            print listfifteen
```

Thanks!

Comment: "*I am new to Python.*"  May I respectfully suggest that you immediately stop working on your current project and read the entire [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial) , including the section where [list slicing is explained](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Sorry! I went over it last week and it slipped my mind to go back and check it. @Robᵩ. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `lst[<start>:<end>]` it would give the elements from `<start>` index (not value) inclusive, to `<end>` (end index) exclusive.

An example might be able to explain this better -

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> lst[0:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> lst[5:10]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Additionally, if you leave, the first `<start>` part empty, it will by default start from `0` , example -

```
>>> lst[:6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Also, if you leave the last `<end>` part empty, it will be default go till the last element ( `len(list)` ) , an example for that -

```
>>> lst[4:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Please note , the `[<start>:<end>]` notation produces copy of the list, not the orignal list, so if you do any changes to this copy (unless the list contains references and you do changes inside the referenced object) , the changes would not reflect in original list.

Example -

```
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> newlst = lst[4:]
>>> newlst
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> newlst[0] = 1
>>> newlst
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Are the values in lst[0:5] the position or the value? Many of the values in my list are the same.

Comment: position , not values

Comment: Welcome, also would advice you to accept answers (by clicking on the tick mark) , if you find they solving the question/problem you had, it would help the community.

Comment: Will do. It's saying I still have to wait three minutes to do so. Thanks so much for your help!